# Finding categories with similar distirbution

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, correlation, distribution

I have a dataframe like the one below:

| profession | country | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| biologist | germany | 30 |
| manager | france | 12 |
| driver | spain | 5 |
| biologist | spain | 23 |

It has 60 different countries and around 250 different professions. 25000 rows in total.

Is there any way I can find out which countries have a similar profession distribution? I'm trying to see if there is any correlation between countries. I'm using pandas, but also have access to Tableau.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad for SO (what do you mean by "similar"?), especially since you provided a very limited dataset.

Comment: you can groupby country and calculate the ratio of profession, then for each country, you got a point in higher dimension space, the dimension is the total number of different professions. they it is up to you how you want to measure the distance between points. some starting visualization might help as well

Comment: Thanks guys. @mozway, what I mean by similar is finding countries that have a similar % of biologists, similar % of managers etc...

Comment: @DaSong thanks a lot for your comment, I think you might be heading into the right direction. Could you please elaborate on your answer? I have grouped by country and calculated what percentage of the country's population has a certain profession. Unsure where to go from here.. Thanks!

Comment: @SunriderDestiny given you have so many different occupations, I would suggest take a look at the clustering algo in sklearn clustering, and try DBSCAN, it does not require number of clusters to use. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html